# How to write Recursive Enum in Dart?

Tags: dart, recursion, enums

```
//In Swift
enum Op{
    case Add
    case Sub
    case Mul
    case Div
}
enum Expr{
    case Value(Int)
    indirect case App(Op,Expr,Expr)
}
```

How can we write above code in Dart?
Please help me.Thank you.

I tried find answer from [document](https://dart.dev/language/enum#declaring-enhanced-enums).

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to *do* in plain English. This way you can get help from all the Dart experts here. Your question is a translation request for experts in Dart *and* Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second Swift `enum` would not be an `enum` declaration in Dart.

A closed set of subclasses is not directly supported in Dart 2.
In Dart 3, you will be able to write it as:

```dart
enum Operator {
  add, sub, mul, div;
}
sealed class Expression {}
final class Value implements Expression {
  final int value;
  Value(this.value);
}
final class Application implements Expression {
  final Expression first;
  final Expression second;
  final Operator operator;
  Application(this.operator, this.first, this.second);
}
```

which you can then process as:

```dart
int evaluate(Expression e) => switch (e) {
      Value v => v.value,
      Application(:var operator, :var first, :var second) =>
        apply(operator, evaluate(first), evaluate(second)),
    };

int apply(Operator operator, int first, int second) => switch (operator) {
      Operator.add => first + second,
      Operator.sub => first - second,
      Operator.mul => first * second,
      Operator.div => first ~/ second,
    };
```

... Although, I'd probably build the functionality into the values, not use switches on the side:

```dart
enum Operator {
  add("+", _add),
  sub("-", _sub),
  mul("*", _mul),
  div("/", _div);
  
  final String _name;
  final int Function(int, int) _compute;
  const Operator(this._name, this._compute);
  
  static int _add(int a, int b) => a + b;
  static int _sub(int a, int b) => a - b;
  static int _mul(int a, int b) => a * b;
  static int _div(int a, int b) => a ~/ b;
  
  @override
  String toString() => _name;
}

sealed class Expression {
  int evaluate();
}

final class Value implements Expression {
  final int value;
  Value(this.value);
  
  @override
  int evaluate() => value;
  
  @override
  String toString() => "$value";
}

final class Application implements Expression {
  final Expression first;
  final Expression second;
  final Operator operator;
  Application(this.operator, this.first, this.second);
  
  @override
  int evaluate() => operator._compute(first.evaluate(), second.evaluate());
    
  @override
  String toString() => "($first $operator $second)";
}
```